# Help with chrome extension message passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a string of values from a background page to my content script in a Google Chrome extension I am making.

The problem I am encountering is that when I try to get the value to the content script, it doesn't go. Here is the code

```
var list1 = "";
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'list'}, function(response) {
      list1 = response.data;
   alert("hey from inside:" + list1 +":"+response.data);
});
alert(list1);
```

The first alert that comes up shows properly saying "hey from inside" and the list I want the content script to have. But then, when I try to alert the variable that I stored it in from outside of that request, it doesn't show the list.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Most (if not all) of the Chrome Extensions API are `asynchronous`. When your `sendRequest` gets fired, the alert will be fired. In this case it will be an empty string. You cannot guarantee the delivery of `list1`, because of this `asynchronous` nature.

Now, what you can do is re-architect your code so that you can take advantage of the asynchronous matter. For example:

### content_script.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'list'}, function(response) {
   onListReceived(response.data)
});

function onListReceived(list) {
  alert(list);
}
```